# why does the encoding not work when using file language?

Tags: php, character-encoding

I have a file for language in my website called tr.lang
I save language variables values there .
I use this in my html header to show the turkish characters :

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=latin-1" />
```

and tr sample :

```
<?php
define("RANK","Sıra");
define("NAME","İsim");
define("TRAFFIC","Hit");
define("POINTS","Puan");
define("COMMENTS","Mesajlar");
define("COMMENT","Mesaj");
define("BONUS","Üye Bonusu");
?>
```

No database involve in this so my problem is how to show this characters correctly.

Note : when I remove the file and just right the values (without variables) it works but when I write them as file and call it in the beginning of my index.php it shows characters like ? and � so what could be the reason of that?

the file call :

```
include_once("{$server_root}include-lng/tr.lang");
```

Comment: What is the encoding of the file `tr.lang` and the one, that loads it?

Comment: Latin-1 isn't an official designation for the charset, it's officially iso-8859-1 and that's what you should use in the meta tag.  Actually you're almost certainly better off using UTF 8.

Comment: How can it be UTF8 if it's written `charset=latin-1` ?

Comment: @ Dainis Abols I mean that I save the tr.lang as utf8 encoding as all my files on the website.

Comment: Then set the meta tag also to `UTF8`

Comment: I did but not working, i tryied a lot of encoding but nothing work (utf-8, iso-8859-1, iso-8859-9, latin-1)

Comment: You don't need *lot of encoding*, just set the encoding of headers ( metas ) to UTF8 and **also** the encoding of the files themselves to `UTF8 w/out BOM`

Answer (score 1):

You have several problems:

1. *Latin-1* is a shorthand way to refer to the encoding, it's actual name is `iso-8859-1`
2. Latin 1 [doesn't support all the characters needed for Turkish](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1#Languages_with_complete_coverage)
3. In a comment, you said "the encoding is utf8", so you are telling the browser to try to decode the text using an encoding you aren't actually using.

The solution:

1. Use UTF-8 (make sure your editor is set to save in that encoding)
2. Tell the browser you are using UTF-8, not Latin-1

Comment: Sorry but it is not working I tried it before also it still same problem when using utf8 or iso-8859-1